# What has happened when webkit shows differently in Chrome and Safari? Have browser prefixes changed for current browser versions?

Tags: html, css, cross-browser, webkit, printing-web-page

Have any of the old prefixes been deprecated in the newer versions of the following browsers?

Chrome:            -webkit-
Internet Explorer: -ms-
Safari:            -webkit-
Firefox:           -moz-

We are attempting to remove PDF's but still want to provide an option for users to print a styled web page print document. I have been creating a [print stylesheet](https://www.medi-library.com/tests/certisites/FIX_css/page_template-zero-border.html) for  a stylized double sided sell sheet, and I have noticed that Safari and webkit do not treat @media print margins the same. Should they because they are both webkit?

The CSS I'm using works in all the browsers but Safari.

```
    @page {
  /*  size: A4 portrait; */
    margin:0;
    }
  @page :header { content: none ;} 
  @page :footer { content: none ;} 

  @media print {
  * {
    -webkit-print-color-adjust: exact !important;   /* Chrome, Safari */
    color-adjust: exact !important;                 /*Firefox*/
  }
  body {
    background-color:#FFFFFF; 
    border: solid px #000;
    margin: 2cm .508cm .508cm; /*.508cm;*/
    }
```

I suspect it's the way I have set up the margins, but I have it working well in Chrome, Explorer, and Firefox.

Safari errors: 
1. header and footer page print information text  shows in margin. 
2. It prints 4 pages and it looks like the page size (letter portrait) is pushing past the page break.

What I did was adjust the size to reduce the runoff.

```
@page page-one page-two{
    /*margin: 0cm;*/
    width: 21.59cm; /* 8.5in */
    height: 25.94cm; /* = margin-top - 27.94cm; /* 11in */
    margin: 0cm;
    /* margin: 30mm 45mm 30mm 45mm;*/ 
    }
  .page-one {
    page-break-after: always;
    }
```

I feel I have made an error. Is there a logical way to set up a styled CSS page so it prints the same on all browsers?

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK Chrome doesn't need `-webkit-` for certain features of CSS from a certain date. I don't know if this is one of these, but it would make sense if the issue was with the `-webkit-` line as only Safari still needs those tags.

Comment: Eyclonus, do you know where I can find information related to the CSS features Chrome  does not need webkit and Browser versions?

Comment: Its only from some specific cases during my studies, but the ones I do remember is Transforms were unprefixed in Chrome 36, and Animations were unprefixed in Chrome 43. I don't know where you could find a list as it seems to be in Chrome dev notes, and most people err on the side of caution. I suppose up-to-date textbooks might have list but its probably unlikely (I have a 2016 textbook that doesn't mention either of above cases). 

Now that you've got me thinking about I'm kind of annoyed that no one thought it important enough to make an easily located list of them.